# Can you populate an Eloquent model without creating an entry in the database using Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

When I'm adding or editing an entry to my database table **websites** I load the instance of the website to be modified (or a blank one for creating a website). This works great, this is my controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Status;
use App\Models\Website;

class WebsitesController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Show / Process the create website form to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $statuses = Status::all();
        $users = User::all();
        $website = Website::find(0);
        return view('admin/websites/create', [
            'statuses' => $statuses,
            'users' => $users,
            'website' => $website
        ]);
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        $statuses = Status::all();
        $users = User::all();
        $website = Website::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin/websites/update', [
            'statuses' => $statuses,
            'users' => $users,
            'website' => $website
        ]);
    }

}
```

The problem is when I submit the form and there is an error. The user is returned to the page and the errors displayed. I also pass the users input back so I can repopulate the form with what they entered. But how can I replace the values in website with the values from input if it's present without actually saving to the database? I've been playing around with this all day and not found a working solution.

My create method is this:

```
public function postCreate(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), Website::rules());
    if ($v->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($v);
    }
    $website = Website::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->action('Admin\HomeController@index')->with('messages', [['text' => 'Website created', 'class' => 'alert-success']]);
}
```

I'm passing the input back to the original form, but the form populates its values from the Website Eloquent model. **How can I get the input from `$request->all()` into `$website`?

I've tried using `fill()`, but I just get `Call to a member function fill() on null` when using it in the create function.

Comment: If you're going to downvote please leave a comment why.

Comment: Read the docs concerning HTTP Requests, especially the part about "old input". http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#old-input

Comment: @Dave That's what I'm doing, when going back to the page I use `return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($v);`, but my question is how do I populate the Eloquent model with input?

Comment: Have you tried using `old('field_name')` in the input value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `create` method attempts to insert a record to the database and returns an instance of the model if it is successful. If you use `create()` with invalid values, the insert will fail. I think this is why there is a `null` instead of an instance of the model, which causes your error:

> Call to a member function fill() on null

Instead of using `create()` You could create the website model without the database insert using

```
$website = new Website;
$website->fill($request->all());
```

before you run the validation. If the validation passes, then you can insert to your database with `$website->save();`, otherwise, it will not try to save, but the model should be available for you to use in your form.